# matplotlib imagesc like for java

Tags: java, matrix, octave

I'm using the function `imagesc` from `matplotlib` in python or `octave` to display a scaled version of a matrix as a color image.

I'm looking for an equivalent in java with no luck.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at http://sourceforge.net/projects/mlplot/

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it seems that this library is only for plotting? I'm looking for the function "imagesc" that exist in matlab.

Comment: @Yann Sagon: Look at line 86: http://sourceforge.net/p/mlplot/svncode/19/tree/MLPlot/src/indiji/mlplot/MLPlot.java

Comment: It seems that this library is what I was looking for, thanks! But unfortunately it's very very slow.